# Dot product of differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, differential-forms

I am reading the [Wikipedia page on Sasakian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasakian_manifold), which has the following definition:

> A Sasakian metric is defined using the construction of the
>   ''Riemannian cone''. Given a Riemannian manifold
>   $(M,g)$, its Riemannian cone is a product
>
> $$(M\times {\Bbb R}^{>0})$$
>
> of $M$ with a half-line ${\Bbb R}^{>0}$,
>   equipped with the ''cone metric''
>
> $$t^2 g + dt^2,$$
>
> where $t$ is the parameter in ${\Bbb R}^{>0}$.
>
> A manifold $M$ equipped with a 1-form $\theta$
>   is contact if and only if the 2-form
>
> $$t^2\,d\theta + 2t\, dt \cdot \theta$$
>
> on its cone is symplectic (this is one of the possible definitions of
>   a contact structure). A contact Riemannian manifold is  Sasakian, if
>   its Riemannian cone with the cone metric is a Kähler manifold with
>   Kähler form
>
> $$t^2\,d\theta + 2t\,dt \cdot \theta.$$

What does it mean to take the dot product $\cdot$ of the one-forms $2t\,dt$ and $\theta$, to somehow get a two-form?  Or is this a typo or variant notation for the wedge / exterior product $\wedge$?

I don't think this is supposed to depend on the metric $g$.

Comment: Hmm, it apparently used to be $\wedge$, but [an edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sasakian_manifold&diff=191528508&oldid=191528050) changed it to $\cdot$, with the comment `\cdot for symmetric forms`.  I don't understand.

Comment: The $dt^2$ is of course a $2$-tensor, but the wedge should be in there for a $2$-form.